# Issue getting HighchartsReact component to fill out container correctly

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, containers, width, reflow

I have a 3 component react app that looks beautifully, with two stock react charts on the top left and top right that split **space evenly** above a nice grid. as seen below.

[image]

Here is the code for my dashboard where you can see the two identical chart components  being inserted into their divs.

```
import React from "react";


import AllocationPanel from "./panels/AllocationPanel";
import PerformancePanel from "./panels/PerformancePanel";
/*import PositionsPanel from "./panels/PositionsPanel";*/
import AgPositionPanel from "./panels/AgPositionPanel";


export default function Dashboard() {
return (
<div className="panels">
  <div className="panel-info">
    
  </div>
  <div className="panel-allocation" >
    <PerformancePanel />
  </div>
  <div className="panel-balance">
    <PerformancePanel />
  </div>
  <div className="panel-positions">
    <AgPositionPanel />
  </div>
</div>
 )
}
```

Because I love highcharts so much I decided to replace the two react charts with two highcharts. Here is the code for the ReactHighcharts  component that I used to replace two original charts. As you can see, a very simple chart.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

const options = {
 title: {
   text: 'highcharts-react-official'
},
  series: [{
  data: [1, 5, 3, 4]
}]
}

export default class AllocationPanel extends Component{
constructor(){
super();
this.chartComponent = React.createRef();

}
componentDidMount(){
this.chartComponent.current.chart.reflow();
}
render() {
 return(
  <HighchartsReact
    highcharts={Highcharts}
    options={options}
    ref={this.chartComponent}
  />
);
}
}
```

When I replace  with the above ReactHighCharts component, the dashboard looks like this, with the highcharts, unequal in size, not filling up their divs and looks to almost have whitespace on either end.

[image]

Do you have any idea what causes the Highcharts to mess up the format/layout of the app, and not fit evenly like with the React Charts in top photo? I have tried reflow fixes, css fixes and cant seem to understand why Highcharts throws everything off.

If you have any ideas, please let me know. I have exhausted other posts, internet searches and cant seem to get the two highcharts to split the window evenly and resize with the window. thanks!

P.S. Here is the CSS for the 3 div containers incase that helps. I feel like I am missing something simple.

```
.panels {
   display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1px auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.panel-info {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.panel-allocation {
  overflow:hidden ;
}
.panel-balance {
  overflow:hidden ;
}
.panel-positions {
grid-column: span 2;
}
.panels > div {
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
.panels {
  grid-template-columns: 1px auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
 }
.panel-positions {
  grid-column: span 2;
  }
 }

 @media (max-width: 750px) {
 .panels {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
  }
.panel-positions {
  grid-column: span 1;
  }
 }
```

Comment: after lots of research, it has something to do with highcharts not obeying the display:grid in the parent div .panels CSS. the original react charts fit into the display:grid fine. I cant figure out why highcharts expands the left side of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was simple. the size of the highchart was pushing on the auto column from display:grid. changing the CSS of the grid to: made the lay out exactly what I wanted.

```
.panels {
display: grid;
grid-gap: 1px;
grid-template-columns: 0px 50% 50%;
grid-template-rows: auto auto;
overflow:hidden;
}
```